# How can I improve the syntax of my AUTOLOADed method names?

Tags: perl, oop

Please forgive me if I misuse some terminology in this post. I'm pushing my Perl and programming skills beyond what I've done before, so I'm not sure what the right terms are for some of the things I'm wanting to do.

I'm writing a small Perl module to make it easier to talk to a program's XML-RPC API. I created a few methods in my module's class to handle the most frequent calls. Then I'm using AUTOLOAD to create methods on-the-fly for the remainder of the API's calls. This works well, and I'm happy with the result.

One improvement I was hoping to make was to improve the syntax of how I call the API's methods. The API has its calls divided into namespaces and uses a period as the namespace separator. So for example, some of the calls are:

- api.login
- api.logout
- user.create
- user.delete

I wasn't able to use a period in the method name when I call it in Perl, so I replace it with an underscore. Here's my AUTOLOAD method.

```
sub AUTOLOAD {
    my $self = shift;
    our $AUTOLOAD;
    (my $method = $AUTOLOAD) =~ s/.*:://s; # remove package name
    $method =~ s/_/./g;
    return if $method =~ /DESTROY/;
    perform_rpc_call( $self, $method, @_ );
}
```

When I make the calls in my Perl code they look like this:

```
$obj->user_delete( $username );
```

Is there a more elegant way to write that than replacing the period with an underscore? I'd prefer to invoke the method as `$obj->user->delete( $username )` if that's possible. Are there modules or Perl design patterns for handling this situation? I've spent the last two days reading the Perl FAQ, searching the net, and searching through CPAN to no avail.

The API I'm communicating with has a call that will return a list of all the calls that it supports. I'm thinking that I could retrieve that in my constructor and somehow use it to make AUTOLOAD do what I want. But I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: This is possible, but not straightforward. You would need to make `$obj->user` return an object of a (different, dynamically-created) class that has a `delete` method. It's not impossible but it's not simple, and I wouldn't have thought it was worthwhile for a little bit of syntactic delight. Why not create the `user` method, and have `$obj->user('delete', $username)`. Or even forget about `AUTOLOAD` altogether and have `$obj->api_call('user.delete', $username);

Comment: @ikegami: That's true, unless there's no theoretical limit to the number of dots an API call identifier can have.

Comment: @Borodin, (Transformed my comment into an answer)

Comment: @Borodin, thanks for the advice. Those are good points. I thought about what you said and decided to stick with what I was doing. Even though ikegami's solution works, I have a gut feeling that what I wanted to do was being too clever. I don't like to be clever.

Comment: You're quite right: cleverness is overrated! I think @ikegami was drawn to post a solution because the problem was an interesting one rather than because it was good advice to follow that route.

Comment: @Borodin, Situations like the OP's (need for proxies) lend themselves well to cleverness (automatic class generation), but you are correct about my motives (interesting, educational)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible if you can tell that `user` is a namespace or member rather than a call.

```
package Class;

sub AUTOLOAD {
    (my $method = our $AUTOLOAD) =~ s/^.*:://s;
    return if $method =~ /DESTROY/;

    my $self = shift;

    return bless([$self, $method], 'Class::Helper');
        if $self->is_namespace($method);

    perform_rpc_call($self, $method, @_);
}


package Class::Helper;

sub AUTOLOAD {
    (my $method = our $AUTOLOAD) =~ s/^.*:://s;
    return if $method =~ /DESTROY/;

    my ($self, $ns) = @{ shift };
    $method = "$ns.$method";

    return bless([$self, $method], 'Class::Helper');
        if $self->is_namespace($method);

    perform_rpc_call($self, $method, @_);
}
```

That will even work with `user.mail.send`.

---

If you can't tell whether `user` is a namespace or a call, your desired syntax won' twork. You'd have to use

```
$obj->user->delete->(@args)  # Error prone. See below
```

or

```
$obj->user->delete->call(@args)  # Same problem, but a little more obvious
```

or

```
$obj->api_call('user.delete', @args)
```

The first option is very error-prone. If you forget that last `->`, the RPC method won't get called. I recommend against that one.

This is how the second option would be implemented:

```
package Class;

sub AUTOLOAD {
    (my $method = our $AUTOLOAD) =~ s/^.*:://s;
    return if $method =~ /DESTROY/;

    my $self = shift;
    return bless([$self, $method], 'Class::Helper');
}


package Class::Helper;

sub AUTOLOAD {
    (my $method = our $AUTOLOAD) =~ s/^.*:://s;
    return if $method =~ /DESTROY/;

    my ($self, $ns) = @{ shift };
    $method = "$ns.$method";
    return bless([$self, $method], 'Class::Helper');
}

sub call {
    my ($self, $method) = @{ shift };
    perform_rpc_call($self, $method, @_);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ikegami. This worked well. I always learn a lot when I read your code.